# Is there a way to use pointers in recursion to find the minimum of an array?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

First of all, I am a beginner coder, so I apologize in advance if this question seems a bit dumb.

I do know of a way of using recursion to find the minimum in an array like this one below.

```
int findMinRec(int A[], int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return A[0];
    return min(A[n-1], findMinRec(A, n-1));
}
```

However, I am trying to figure out a method using recursion and a pointer. Something like this:

```
const int *min(const int arr[], int arrSize) {
```

Is there a simple method to doing this? I tried reworking the standard way, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do this with a pointer.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that is a bit of help, but still doesn't solve the pointer problem unfortunately.

Comment: Do you want your function to return a pointer or a value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to adjust to returning a pointer instead of a value, meaning you cannot use `std::min()`. Expand it inline and adjust it.
I also renamed your function to make it obvious it returns a pointer to the smallest element, instead of being a restricted re-implementation of `std::min()`.
Another important point is making it tail-recursive, so the compiler can easily optimize it to iterative and omit adding stack-frames.

```
const int *min_p(const int arr[], int arrSize) {
    if (arrSize == 1)
        return arr;
    return min_p(arr + (arr[arrSize - 1] < *arr), arrSize - 1);
}
```

Also of interest, both your original code and `min_p()` lead to UB if `arrSize` is not positive...

Comment: The last point is moot - it will be lead to UB if arrSize generally falls out from the allowed range of values, and being non-negative is one example of that.

Comment: @SergeyA: The original could be extended slightly so if `arrSize` is not positive, the answer is `INT_MIN` (that also leads to a nice iterative implementation). `min_p()` could be extended to return `nullptr` in that case...

Comment: While it could, I does not necessarily should. Requiring valid range could be simply specified as a contract.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const int *_min(const int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    if (arrSize == 1)
    {
        return arr;
    }
    const int *t = _min(arr + 1, arrSize - 1);
    if (*t < *arr)
    {
        return t;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I need! However, I am getting a compiler error consist of:  invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’

Comment: This unfortunately is not tail-recursive, so even if the compiler knows the transformation...

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand that `A` **is** a pointer. So if you want to return a pointer instead of the value, just do it. Change `return A[0];` to `return A;`.